# Why won't my google web app won't load on my google site in Safari?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, safari

I made a simple Google Site that runs a Google Web App that I wrote and published. The Web App pulls data from a Google Sheet. The Web App runs perfectly if you view my site in Chrome, but doesn't load at all if you view the site in Safari (the rest of the Site content loads fine though). Why would this be? Are Google Web Apps supported in Safari?

In case it matters, below is what my Web App's doGet() outputs. It's not pretty, I know. I'm planning to learn how to use templated HTML outputs. Figuring out how to output HTML code as a string is a stepping stone, so to speak.

```js
var HTMLString = "<font face=arial><table align=center><tr><td>" +
  "<h3 align = center>Album no. " +
  "<font color=#1abc9c>" + albumrand + "</font> picked by <font color=#1abc9c>" + pick + "</font>:" +
  "</h3>" +
  "<h2 align = center><font color=#1abc9c>" + title + "</font>" +
  "</br>by</br>" +
  "<font color=#1abc9c>" + artist + "</font>" +
  "</h2>" +
  "<h4 align=center> Refresh page for another pick</br>| Pull down (mobile) | F5 (desktop) |</h4>" +
  "</td></tr></table></font>";

return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLString);
```

Comment: Could you check if your site loads in the incognito mode of Google Chrome?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: It does not, it gives "accounts.google.com refused to connect" and the little 'oh snap' sad page icon, in the place the code should load. In Safari it's different though, that part of the page just stays completely blank.

Comment: Are you using Google Sites? Does [this](https://support.google.com/sites/thread/10581343?hl=en) help?

Comment: I am using Google Sites... and am I not clear on what that person means by "Instead of selecting the script from the Apps Script list in the Manage Site area, I used the Publish - Deploy as Web App URL from the script's own page, then it works as expected. "  I deployed my script as a Web App, and used that URL to insert it into my Google Site. I am using the 'New' Google Sites, not the 'Classic'.

Comment: I just switched the access on my Web App deployment from "anyone" to "anyone, even anonymous" and now it works in incognito! I'll have to check to see if that solved the Safari issue.

Comment: This must have been the reason, in Safari you are probably also considered as anynomous since you are not signed in with a Google account.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that when deploying the Web App, I had the 'access' set to "anyone". I redeployed, changing the access to "anyone, even anonymous", and now it works in both Chrome-Inognito and  Safari.